# Save taxonomy term's lineage

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

In Drupal 7 when editing a node and saving a taxonomy term that has parents, how can I attach the parent lineage to the node as well?

ie:

```
Honda
 -> Civic
Toyota
 -> Corolla
```

If I choose Corolla, Toyota would also be attached to the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't need to do this; whatever function you'd want for this, would be able to do this programmatically for you.  For example, if you want all of these displayed on the page, I know there's a possibility to display the full hierarchy in breadcrumbs - it's either somewhere in core, or a module.  If you want searches of "Honda" also to show Civics ... like if you've set up a Views page with an exposed filter for this vocabulary - you'll see that in the options for these filters, there's also an option to show nodes associated with "children" of the taxonomy term you're searching for.

In order to write code yourself for a template file that displays the taxonomy term's parents, see `taxonomy_get_parents($tid)`: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/7

Comment: Setting up a view will work, but I can't seem to find the options to do this...  How do I setup a filter to show anything tagged with Honda or children of Honda?

Comment: Just had a look at the Views interface - It's Filters > Taxonomy ID with depth - OR Arguments > Taxonomy ID with depth. So the argument is going to need to be the term ID, and not the term itself (i.e., the word).  This means you'll probably want to do some programming if you want it "nice" and have the actual word in the url - grab that word with arg(), use a function to grab the corresponding id of the taxonomy term (go to http://api.drupal.org & search taxonomy), and then create/embed the view with the term ID as one of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks James, the Filters > Taxonomy ID with depth should do what I want but in Drupal 7 it seems to be broken: http://drupal.org/node/1095248 (it works fine in Drupal 6)

Comment: Now that is one of the huge bummer moments in Drupal sitebuilding that sometimes makes you want to go running down the street yelling while ripping out your hair - little features you expect to be there but are buggy in a new version.  Strength to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for this. Enable the "save lineage" setting to achieve it.